# powermockito for private methods in akka actors

Tags: java, akka, powermock, testkit

I have the following actor

```
import akka.actor.AbstractActor;
import akka.event.Logging;
import akka.event.LoggingAdapter;

public class MyActor extends AbstractActor {
  private final LoggingAdapter log = Logging.getLogger(getContext().getSystem(), this);

  @Override
  public Receive createReceive() {
    return receiveBuilder()
      .match(String.class, s -> {
        log.info("Received String message: {}", s);
         doSomethingNow();
      })
      .matchAny(o -> log.info("received unknown message"))
      .build();
  }

private MyObject doSomethingNow() {
/// code
return MyObject;
    }
```

Now to unit test this actor, should I mock the method 'doSomethingNow'? From the PowerMockito doc, it looks like I also need to mock the class which is the actor but the TestKit already offers a framework around mocking actors, whats the right way to test this actor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing you could do here is to use dependency injection. Ideally - your actors shouldn't contain any business logic in them - they need to route the message to the underlying services.

In your case you could have a separated service, e.g `DoerService` with `doSomethingNow` method in it. Then you can inject it via dependency injection framework of your choice, as shown below:

```
import akka.actor.AbstractActor;
import akka.event.Logging;
import akka.event.LoggingAdapter;

public class MyActor extends AbstractActor {
  private final LoggingAdapter log = Logging.getLogger(getContext().getSystem(), this);

  @Inject
  private DoerService doerService;

  @Override
  public Receive createReceive() {
    return receiveBuilder()
      .match(String.class, s -> {
        log.info("Received String message: {}", s);
         doerService.doSomethingNow();
      })
      .matchAny(o -> log.info("received unknown message"))
      .build();
  }
```

This way you do not even need Powermock to accomplish your task. Mockito will be more than enough.

**IMHO, whenever Mockito is not enough to unit test your code then most likely something is wrong with your design. A code should be not only well written and reusable - it should also be testable.**

Comment: Ideally, it's another interface of the class (following dependency inversion principle from SOLID). But whenever it's beans for internal use only (e.g when you do not build a library or API used by others) my personal opinion is that having it as a separate class without interface would be sufficient.